# Velocity/Mocha not properly registering file changes

Tags: meteor

I am having trouble using Mocha/Velocity in my project. I generated the sample tests and they run successfully. However, if I copy the first "it(...)" , rename it and try to assert if 10 is equal 10, the test would not get registered. Velocity still only shows 1 test in the file. When I switch from chai.assert to the expect. syntax, the test magically gets registered. But then, when I change it from expect(10).to.equal(10) to (15)(10) it would still pass, meaning that the change in the variables doesn't get registered...

Is this a know issue, anything I am doing wrong?
This is the code I am running after playing around and trying different things:

```
if (typeof MochaWeb !== 'undefined'){
  MochaWeb.testOnly(function(){
    var expect=require('chai').expect;
    describe("a group of tests", function(){
      it("should respect equality", function(){
        expect(5).to.equal(5);
      });
      it("should respect equality again", function(){
        expect(10).to.equal(10);
        });

      it("should respect equality again2", function(){
          expect(15).to.equal(15);
      });

      it("should respect equality again3", function(){
        expect(10).to.equal(20);
      });

      it("should not be equal", function(){
          expect(12).to.not.equal(15);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

"should respect equality again2" fails, because it tries to assert if 10 is 15 (which are the variables I had before) and "should not be equal" fails because of a syntax error that I made in an earlier version. "should expect equality again3" actually passes, because I asserted if (20) equals(20) in an earlier version.

**EDIT** Ok, the behaviour is getting weirder and weirder. I delete the `var expect = require('chai').expect;`
part and changed all the assertions back to the `assert.` syntax. Now I am getting an error on all tests, saying that "expect" is not defined. I did not save until I changed all the assertions, so meteor must have saved automatically and now doesn't register the file changes again....